# How to do a cmis query for file information related to an ibm bpm instance?

Tags: websphere, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I am trying to get the information of all the files related to an instance of ibm bpm but the following query does not work for me and there is no error in the javascript console either. I am using ECM Document List and in configuration I am adding a variable which contains the query.

`"SELECT cmis:name, IBM_BPM_Document_FileNameURL,IBM_BPM_Document_UserId FROM IBM_ WHERE IBM_BPM_Document_ProcessInstanceId = 75774"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you are using and external ECM server and not the embedded ECM that comes along with IBM BPM/BAW.

Looking at the problem, I would approach the debugging in the following order;

1. Use a relevant ECM browser (ACCE in case of Filenet) to check if the
   documents have a property that holds the value for the instanceID.
   Because, by default external ECM servers don't have such a document
   property.
2. If the document has such a property, then use that in the
   "WHERE" clause of the query. If it doesn't then talk to whoever
   maintains the ECM environment to create such a property and make
   sure that is set properly (to the correct instanceId) for the
   documents.

Another solution if you have access to it can be using the "BPM Document List" and "BPM File Uploader" which has the feature (as a configuration option) to associate documents with the current process instance.

Comment: It is the integrated ibm baw server, but I need to pass a query to it in order to get the documents related to an instance. And only the control that I am currently using allows to add the query to it as part of the configuration. Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are using the "Embedded ECM Server". In that case, can you please use this query "SELECT cmis:objectId, cmis:name, IBM_BPM_Document_FileNameURL, IBM_BPM_Document_ProcessInstanceId, cmis:lastModificationDate, IBM_BPM_Document_UserId, cmis:contentStreamMimeType, IBM_BPM_Document_FileType, cmis:versionSeriesId FROM IBM_BPM_Document ORDER BY cmis:lastModificationDate DESC" and update the question with the output screenshot/results.